# In Ruby, need help linking an Array

Tags: ruby

I'm brand new to Ruby and I'm tryna have fun with it, by creating a fake paternity test. Is my code suitable to link a users input to an already defined array?

```
array1 = [a,b,ab,o]

Print "mother blood type"

user_input1 = gets.chomp

if user_input1 != array1[]
  puts "try again"
else 
  puts user_input1 = array1[]
end 
end
```

Comment: For one, your code is not valid Ruby and will not run.

Answer (score 1):

I will write the code as below :

```
array1 = %w(a b ab o)

puts "mother blood type" 
user_input1 = "o" 
# I have hard-code for testing,you can put user_input1 = gets.chomp

if array1.include? user_input1
  puts user_input1
else 
  puts "try again" 
end 
# >> mother blood type
# >> o
```

- In your code `array1 = [a,b,ab,o]` is not a valid array. You can write it as `%w(a b ab o)` or `array1 = ['a','b','ab','o']`
- `Print "mother blood type"` is wrong statement.Nothing there is `Print` rather `print` exist.
- your `if - end` block is not valid also. see here - [**Ruby If, Else If Command Syntax**](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/ruby/ruby-if-else-if-command-syntax/).

Comment: Thkyou, This is literally my abs first time, tryna write a ruby program on my own. I'm glad that you took time to help guide me.